# Is there any 'Metamask-like' app for Bitcoin?

Tags: development, signature, ethereum, javascript

9 months ago someone asked this same question: [Metamask-like web3 inject for bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91045/metamask-like-web3-inject-for-bitcoin) but I was wondering if there had been be any changes since then.

I'm currently looking for a Chrome extension that allows you to validate Bitcoin users based on their wallets, It does not matter if it's not a Chrome extension, I just need some app that could accomplish this.

I'm working in a project using Metamask for login users, and I need to find out if there is a way of archieving this with Bitcoin (and other cryptocurrencies), so if you know something about the topic it would be great to hear you.

Comment: No, because Bitcoin doesn't have a (privacy-invading) standard web API like web3.js. No news in the last one year about that.

Comment: Bitcoin wallets are sets of addresses derived from master keys, while ethereum is account balance. As @MCCCS mentioned, bitcoin is also much more privacy-focused than ethereum.

Comment: Microsoft is apparently building a 'decentralized identity platform' which utilizes the bitcoin network. I haven't read much about it, I don't know if they have much code currently available,  but here is a link to their site: https://identity.foundation/